# Internal Error while launching Application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created my first Android application and I am trying to run it on Eclipse. When I click the play button it gives me an error,

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
Path for project must have only one segment.
```

Now I tried to configure the run configurations but I was still unable to run my program.

I would be very thankful if I can get some help.

EDIT:
[image]

[image]

It doesnt let me browse nor write the name.(Please right click to view larger images)

Answer (score 51):

This cryptic message usually tries to tell you "Please enter a name and project in your run configuration".

It annoyed me enough to actually write a blogpost about it, for some more info http://androblip.huiges.nl/2011/02/20/eclipseavd-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segment/

Check your run configurations for a name and project :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope you not write that blog post in 15 minutes to get 1 visitor ;)

Comment: Haha, no, see the date (2011/02/20) and the comments below the article. It's just a really strange error I felt the need to write about.

Comment: When I go to the configurations, there are no projects in browse. What do I do now?

Comment: Strange? Did you start your project as an Android project? Maybe it filters on that? Also, you can try just typing the name of your project (topmost word in the tree), but I doubt that works, as it probably matches it to the "browse" list...

Comment: Yes I started the project as Android Project.

Comment: Could it be because of the spaces in your project name (just guessing now)

Comment: It's one thing to try and find a needle in a haystack...its another thing when the haystack is actively trying to sabotage you.

Comment: @Nanne thank you so much. it works like charm but why `run` button doesnt work! and every time i want start my project i should select triangle next to RUN button and select new_configuration

Answer (score 17):

Hi First of All my step in below may used you following:::

Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings: 1. select "Launching New_configuration" 2. Delete 3. OK

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings:

1. select "Launching New_configuration"
2. edit
3. browse project -> choose my project name , choose target device and complete the missing configuration
4. OK

Answer (score 2):

It is because a New_configuration is added in Project Run/Debug setting . So you have to remove this New_configuration.
Go to your Project's Properties.. Select Run/Debug Settings and Choose New_configuration under Launch Configuration. Select this New_configuration and delete it. Apply and ok..

Answer (score 0):

You having more than one project in your workspace. so you need to select your project after clicking run configuration in the Android tab

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you specified the (only) Launch configuration for the project (Properties > Run/Debug Settings),you forgot to specify the Project name:

[image]

Hmmm... I thought that it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is a bit different. even after below does not work for me:

1. Entering project name in runConfiguration.
   2.Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings: 1. select "Launching New_configuration" 2. Delete 3. OK

The only way I solved the problem is restarting my eclipse and creating new run configuration.

thanks.